# What is value of this equation?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logarithms

$\displaystyle \frac{\log a}{\log b}=\frac{1}{2}$, $\displaystyle \;\frac{\log c}{\log d}=\frac{3}{4}$, $\; a-c=9$.

What is $b-d$ equal to?

Comment: What you wrote in the last line is ... *what* ? Given data, something you came up with...?

Comment: It isn't determined.  Take $\{a,b,c,d\}=\{x,x^2,x-9,(x-9)^{4/3}\}$ for any $x$.

Comment: The pattern of integer solutions may be of some interest:  $a\in \{17,36,73,134,225,352\cdots\}$.  OEIS doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As I mentioned, even if you require integer solutions (which you do not specify) the answer is not uniquely determined.  The quadruples $\{17,289,8,16\}$ and $\{36,1296,27,81\}$ both work, just to name two, and clearly $b-d$ is not a fixed value.

Comment: The question is find b-c with the given information. The answer is -3. It appeared on my exam and i think the question is undefined?

Comment: Your post asks for $b-d$, not $b-c$, but neither of them are determined.  I expect you have not reprinted the question accurately.

Comment: It was a typo,  it was asking for b-d. Im writing what the question said

Comment: Why did you delete the equations $b=a^2$ and $d=c^{4/3}$ from the question? They were the only things indicating that you have made any attempt to solve the problem. (Also, they were correct.)

Comment: Do not repost questions. This should never have happened: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992535/what-is-the-value-of-this-equation

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln(\text{a})}{\ln(\text{b})}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{\ln(\text{c})}{\ln(\text{d})}=\frac{3}{4}\\
\text{a}-\text{c}=9
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space
\begin{cases}
\ln(\text{b})=2\ln(\text{a})\\
3\ln(\text{d})=4\ln(\text{c})\\
\text{a}-\text{c}=9
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space
\begin{cases}
\text{b}=\text{a}^2\\
\text{d}^3=\text{c}^4\\
\text{a}-\text{c}=9
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space
\begin{cases}
\text{b}=\left(9+\text{c}\right)^2\\
\text{d}^3=\text{c}^4\\
\text{a}=9+\text{c}
\end{cases}
$$